# How to simulate javascript keypress from Chrome's JavaScript console (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to use **Chrome's developer console** to simulate N times (e.g. 10000) JavaScript's `keypress` with keycode = 50 (key: "2" in keyboard), not within a single elements, but at page level.

I need to achieve this result without modifying the source code, to test a web application behavior under multiple user interactions.

I found different answers on Stack Overflow but most of them are based on jQuery.

I tried to use:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
>> undefined
evt.initKeyEvent ("keypress", true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50); 
>> undefined is not a function
```

followed by **event dispatch** but it doesn't work.

Also I don't know how shall insert a **for cycle** from Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `KeyboardEvent` constructor and the `dispatchEvent` method. To simulate a keypress with keycode 50 (key "2") N times, you can create a function and use a for loop. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this in the Chrome developer console:

Open the Chrome developer console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J / Cmd+Opt+J on macOS).
Copy and paste the following code snippet into the console and press Enter:

1. Open the Chrome developer console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J / Cmd+Opt+J on macOS).
2. Copy and paste the following code snippet into the console and press Enter:

```
function simulateKeyPress(keyCode, numTimes) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    const keyPressEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      keyCode: keyCode,
      which: keyCode,
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(keyPressEvent);
  }
}
```

3. Now that the function is defined, you can use it to simulate a keypress with keycode 50 (key "2") N times. For example, if you want to simulate it 10,000 times, simply call the function like this:

```
simulateKeyPress(50, 10000);
```